# How to access a static member overriden in an inheriting class?

Tags: php

Here's an example

```
class derp {
    public static $importantVariable = "default";
    public function doSomethingImportant() {
        echo self::$importantVariable;
    }
}

class fancy extends derp {
    public static $importantVariable = "special";
}

$fancyInstance = new fancy();
$fancyInstance->doSomethingImportant();
```

Ok so, I want to override the static member "importantVariable" and make it so that inherited functions use the overriden value instead of the base class value.

In this case it says "default" but I want it to say "special", how do I make it refer to the overriden value?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
class derp {
    public static $importantVariable = "default";
    public function doSomethingImportant() {
        echo static::$importantVariable; //HERE
    }
}

class fancy extends derp {
    public static $importantVariable = "special";
}

$fancyInstance = new fancy();
$fancyInstance->doSomethingImportant();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `self`, use `static`:

```
class derp {
    public static $importantVariable = "default";
    public function doSomethingImportant() {
        echo static::$importantVariable;
    }
}
```

The `static` keyword takes advantage of [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) so that it will take on the value defined in the concrete class being used at runtime rather than the class that the reference just happens to be made from, as is the case with the `self` keyword.